# How to generate code to RTL with blackbox?

Tags: chisel, black-box

When I want to convert code chisel to verilog with black box, I have error. How can I fix it?

```
[error] /data/workspace/chisel/chisel3-3.1.8/src/main/scala/tap/dti_bypass_register.scala:45:18: overloaded method value execute with alternatives:
```

```
import chisel3._
import chisel3.util._
  class dti_bypass_register extends BlackBox with HasBlackBoxResource {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val clk_DR          = Input (Clock())// Bypass register clock
    val TDI             = Input (UInt(1.W))// data in
    val bypass_en       = Input (Bool())// enable signal
    val captureDR       = Input (Bool())// captureDR signal

    val TDO_bypass      = Output (UInt(1.W))// Serial data out
  })
    setResource("/dti_bypass_register.v")

}

object dti_bypass_registerDriver extends App {
  chisel3.Driver.execute(args, () => new dti_bypass_register)
}
```

Comment: [error] chisel/chisel3-3.1.8/src/main/scala/tap/dti_bypass_register.scala:45:18: overloaded method value execute with alternatives:
[error]   (args: Array[String],dut: () => chisel3.experimental.RawModule)chisel3.ChiselExecutionResult <and>
[error]   (optionsManager: firrtl.ExecutionOptionsManager with chisel3.HasChiselExecutionOptions with firrtl.HasFirrtlOptions,dut: () => chisel3.experimental.RawModule)chisel3.ChiselExecutionResult
[error]  cannot be applied to (Array[String], () => dti_bypass_register)
[error]   chisel3.Driver.execute(args, () => new dti_bypass_register)

Answer (score 1):

Chisel does not accept BlackBoxes as the top Module. Since BlackBoxes are simply interfaces that we emit a Verilog instantiation for, there's not really anything for Chisel to do with them.

Comment: oh, this is error and now I fixed it. Thanks so much!